# Line Drawn On C# Form Too Long

Tags: c#, forms, system.drawing

I haven't seen any posts relating to this but a line drawn on my form is supposed to stop 5px before the boarder around the form but it doesn't.  The purpose of this line is to separate two different user controls on one form if need be.

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if (optionalSecondPanel != null)
        {
            Graphics g;

            g = e.Graphics;

            Pen myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
            g.DrawLine(myPen, mainPanel.Width + 5, btnPannel.Bottom + 5, mainPanel.Width + 5, this.Height - 5);
            myPen.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

However when drawn on the screen the line separating the user controls goes all the way to the bottom of the form.  It doesn't stop when it is supposed to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
g.DrawLine(myPen, mainPanel.Width + 5, btnPannel.Bottom - 5, mainPanel.Width + 5, this.Height - 5);
```

I believe .Bottom increases going down, so if you subtract 5 it should raise the bottom of the bar.

Comment: So if I change it to `this.Height - 50` the bottom of the line comes up and is visible.  Why then is -5 not working/visible.

Comment: Perhaps the bottom of the panel is lower than you expect?  Experiment with larger values and let me know what happens.

Comment: So if I increase the number I subtract by then my line shows.  My form is 612px high so `this.Height - 5` should result in a line that stops before the end.

Comment: Are you saying that it's working or that you expect it to be working with the -5 and it's not?

Comment: It isn't working with -5 but I expect it should.  If I used a larger number than 5 (say -50) it would work.

Comment: Without Knowing you're front end declarations, I cannot help further.  Try using Firebug or Chrome dev tools to confirm that the front end is displaying as you expect.